# 'AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'AsSyncOverAsync' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I have update my unity project dlls and after that i am getting this error

> 'AvroDeserializer' does not contain a definition for
>   'AsSyncOverAsync' and no accessible extension method 'AsSyncOverAsync'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'AvroDeserializer'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

at this line

```
  .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
```

I don't know why this is not method is not available. Here are my dll files:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to reproduced a small solution only with this code in `program.cs`, I can build the solution and see the `AsSyncOverAsync` extension method which located in  `Confluent.Kafka.SyncOverAsync` namespace.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> consumerConfig = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { }))
        using (var consumer =
            new Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(consumerConfig)
                .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                .Build()) { }
    }
}
```

This is the `*.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Confluent.Kafka" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.Avro" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It looks like you are missing the `Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.Avro` package so try manually install them both from Nuget.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, it was already installed. My silly mistake was i have used own AvroDeserializer class earlier.